# Labeling inside align and cases

Tags: align, labels, cases

I want to label my system of equation with align and cases,

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\begin{aligned}
\Delta u &= a \quad&&\text{\,\,in\,\,}  \Omega\setminus B_{\rho}(0)=\Omega_\rho  \\
u(x)  &= b \quad&&\text{\,\,on\,\,} \partial B_{\rho}(0)\\
u(x)  &= c \quad&&\text{\,\,on\,\,} \partial \Omega
\end{aligned}
\end{cases}
\label{1}
\end{equation}
```

I can do it with this long code, is there any shorter commands to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use the cases environment for this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}




\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{array}{rll}
\Delta u &= a \quad&\text{in~}  \Omega\setminus B_{\rho}(0)=\Omega_\rho  \\
u(x)  &= b \quad&\text{on~} \partial B_{\rho}(0)\\
u(x)  &= c \quad&\text{on~} \partial \Omega
\end{array}\right.
\label{1}
\end{equation}



\end{document}
```